# does promise catch too much errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, promise

I am writing promise following this style in the [doc](https://github.com/kriskowal/q):

    `Q.fcall(promisedStep1)
    .then(promisedStep2)
    .then(promisedStep3)
    .then(promisedStep4)
    .then(function (value4) {
        // Do something with value4
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // Handle any error from all above steps
    })
    .done();`

The catch clause will catch any errors including typos. 
However, according to [nodejs dos:](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_warning_don_t_ignore_errors)

> By the very nature of how throw works in JavaScript, there is almost never any way to safely  "pick up where you left off", without leaking references, or creating some other sort of undefined brittle state. The safest way to respond to a thrown error is to shut down the process.

Some kinds of errors would throw out if we are writing code in the callback style, but not in promise style
This is really confusing me. How should I avoid leaking references when writing in promise.

Thanks~

Comment: If you have things like open file handles that needs to be cleaned up, then you HAVE to have a `.catch()` somewhere in scope of the open file handles so you can clean them up if an exception is thrown.  This is just your responsibility as a programmer.  In nodejs, file handles don't clean themselves up.  Same with some other resources like sockets.

Comment: In each scope in your chain, you have to ask yourself the question - if an exception is thrown here, is there something I need to clean up.  If the answer is yes, then you have to catch the exception there.  You can rethrow the exception after cleaning up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example shows good promise chain, including using `.done()` to make sure any unhandled exceptions are thrown from the promise chain to the outside application.
As far as references and error handling: the promise chains only guarantee than an error will be forwarded to the `.catch` callback. If there is no way to clean up the state when the error is thrown - you are out of luck. For example

```js
Q.fncall(function firstStep() {
  var fs = open file reference
  foo.bar; // generates ReferenceError
}).then(function somethingElse() {
  ...
}).catch(function (err) {
  // we have caught ReferenceError
  // but we cannot clean up open fs reference!
}).done();
```

We caught the error, but the catch handler cannot close `fs` reference. This is what it means that even with promises we have to think how to clean up resources in case of an error.

Comment: good example. but how should we handle this? rethrow it to let the process die?

Comment: @bpceee if you expect node to have reasonable performance you should definitely handle your errors. Otherwise you're in a very problematic position since startup time in Node servers is pretty slow.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum u r right, but what if we catch an unexpected error. say it's thrown from a third part library, and it may introduce leaks. i think we should let the process die in this case. It's one thing you need not to consider when you programming in callback style.

Comment: Sure you'd consider it, you'd have the exact same problem with callbacks. Shutting down the server on any error is not a reasonable behavior.